# Why do I can't execute my string?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I create a string dynamically to perform this by `EXECUTE`. It throws an exception - why?
As you see I return my string before I try to execute it. When I run this *result* in a MySQL client instead of `CALL procedure ()` it works flawlessly.
If I try to return my `PREPARE`d string I get no result. It seems `PREPARE` kinda breaks my string.

The exception

> Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT movie_name, @ClearLOGOs:=IF((SELECT COUNT(image_id) FROM movie_images WHE' at line 1

The most important sql

```
SET set_part = CONCAT(set_part, '; ');
SET having_part = CONCAT(having_part, ' ORDER BY completeness ASC');
SET completeness_part = CONCAT(completeness_part, ') AS completeness');
SET complete_select = CONCAT('',set_part, select_part, completeness_part, ' FROM movie_items ',having_part);

SET @exec = complete_select;
SELECT @exec;
PREPARE _exec FROM @exec;
EXECUTE _exec;
```

The result (unformatted, exact copy)

```
SET @ClearLOGOs=0, @ClearART=0, @cdART=0, @Movie_Backgrounds=0, @Movie_Banner=0, @HD_Movie_Logos=0, @Movie_Thumbs=0, @HD_ClearART=0, @Movie_Poster=0; SELECT movie_name, @ClearLOGOs:=IF((SELECT COUNT(image_id) FROM movie_images WHERE image_active = 'y' AND image_type = '10' AND image_movie_tmdb_id = movie_tmdb_id) > 0, 0, 1) AS ClearLOGOs, @ClearART:=IF((SELECT COUNT(image_id) FROM movie_images WHERE image_active = 'y' AND image_type = '11' AND image_movie_tmdb_id = movie_tmdb_id) > 0, 0, 1) AS ClearART, @cdART:=IF((SELECT COUNT(image_id) FROM movie_images WHERE image_active = 'y' AND image_type = '12' AND image_movie_tmdb_id = movie_tmdb_id) > 0, 0, 1) AS cdART, @Movie_Backgrounds:=IF((SELECT COUNT(image_id) FROM movie_images WHERE image_active = 'y' AND image_type = '16' AND image_movie_tmdb_id = movie_tmdb_id) > 0, 0, 1) AS Movie_Backgrounds, @Movie_Banner:=IF((SELECT COUNT(image_id) FROM movie_images WHERE image_active = 'y' AND image_type = '19' AND image_movie_tmdb_id = movie_tmdb_id) > 0, 0, 1) AS Movie_Banner, @HD_Movie_Logos:=IF((SELECT COUNT(image_id) FROM movie_images WHERE image_active = 'y' AND image_type = '23' AND image_movie_tmdb_id = movie_tmdb_id) > 0, 0, 1) AS HD_Movie_Logos, @Movie_Thumbs:=IF((SELECT COUNT(image_id) FROM movie_images WHERE image_active = 'y' AND image_type = '24' AND image_movie_tmdb_id = movie_tmdb_id) > 0, 0, 1) AS Movie_Thumbs, @HD_ClearART:=IF((SELECT COUNT(image_id) FROM movie_images WHERE image_active = 'y' AND image_type = '26' AND image_movie_tmdb_id = movie_tmdb_id) > 0, 0, 1) AS HD_ClearART, @Movie_Poster:=IF((SELECT COUNT(image_id) FROM movie_images WHERE image_active = 'y' AND image_type = '29' AND image_movie_tmdb_id = movie_tmdb_id) > 0, 0, 1) AS Movie_Poster,(@ClearLOGOs + @ClearART + @cdART + @Movie_Backgrounds + @Movie_Banner + @HD_Movie_Logos + @Movie_Thumbs + @HD_ClearART + @Movie_Poster) AS completeness FROM movie_items  HAVING ClearLOGOs > 0 OR ClearART > 0 OR cdART > 0 OR Movie_Backgrounds > 0 OR Movie_Banner > 0 OR HD_Movie_Logos > 0 OR Movie_Thumbs > 0 OR HD_ClearART > 0 OR Movie_Poster > 0   ORDER BY completeness ASC
```

Comment: keep removing small parts from the query until it works, then the last thing you removed was the problem

Comment: What language are you using? In PHP, for example, the queries must not contain `;`. Try doing each query individually.

Comment: @rendon sorry for not being clear enough - I perform all this actions on a mysql client.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use more than one query within prepared statements.

> SQL syntax for prepared statements does not support multi-statements (that is, multiple statements within a single string separated by “;” characters).

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html